# .htaccess not working on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: .htaccess, apache-2.4, ubuntu-14.04

Here is relevant code from 000-default.conf:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

But when I put a .htaccess even with nothing in it every site except for the index returns a 403 error. And in phpinfo() mod_rewrite isn't there.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at following, as some syntax has changed from 2.2 to 2.4:

[Upgrading to 2.4 from 2.2 - Apache HTTP Server Version 2.5](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/upgrading.html)

here are few examples:

```
In this example, all requests are denied.

2.2 configuration:

Order deny,allow
Deny from all
2.4 configuration:

Require all denied
In this example, all requests are allowed.

2.2 configuration:

Order allow,deny
Allow from all
2.4 configuration:

Require all granted
In the following example, all hosts in the example.org domain are allowed access; all other hosts are denied access.

2.2 configuration:

Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from example.org
2.4 configuration:

Require host example.org
```

Comment: I've updated my syntax but it still returns a 403 error when I add .htaccess